# How to protect from dangerous bash commands?

Tags: linux, security, bash, bashrc

When using *bash* with or without `sudo` there are many traps. For example when logged in as root between

```
rm -rf ~/bin
```

and

```
rm -rf /bin
```

there is just one character but this difference can make you quite unhappy.

To protect myself a little bit of such disasters I use this in my `/etc/bash.bashrc` (systemwide `.bashrc`):

```
if [ $UID -ne 0 ]; then
    # ask me before deleting
    alias rm='rm -i'
else
    # do not delete / or prompt if deleting more than 3 files at a time
    alias rm='rm -I --preserve-root'
fi
```

With this, I at least have to confirm deleting before running into disaster.
Maybe there are even more dangerous commands as rm...

What are the most dangerous bash-commands and to protect myself from day-to-day disasters?

Comment: You can also add `-i` to `cp` or `mv` to protect against dangerous overwrites.

Comment: Have you tried *not* logging in as root?

Comment: You never know when you are going to type `--no-preserve-root` [accidentally](http://serverfault.com/questions/587102/monday-morning-mistake-sudo-rm-rf-no-preserve-root).

Comment: @ceejayoz: most of the time I'm not logged in a root. this is why in `/etc/bashrc` bashrc there are aliases specific aliases to the root login.

Comment: @ceejayoz Whether you are root or using sudo, the same risks apply.  Some things simply require root.  Linux has not yet evolved to the point of removing the root account.

Comment: @Aaron I find it a lot easier to remember to check my commands more carefully when using sudo. Easy to forget you're in as root.

Comment: @ceejayoz I understand what you mean.  Another option for that is the bash prompt.  If root, make it red.  If not root, it is green.  This is of course a much more complicated topic that gets into server management philosophies, role based access controls with proper file permissions that reduce the need for root and sysadmin experience and training.  You may have the experience and dicipline to use sudo properly, but most do not.  They either disable pw checking, or set the token cache so high that they only get prompted once.  Many folks also use sudo su -

Comment: @Aaron, "Linux has not yet evolved..." actually, it has: SELinux. I find it easier to just not have to login to machines at all, and just use a configuration management tool to do everything. Also, anyone still using `sudo su -` needs to be given a copy of the `sudo`(8) manpage and a written test.

Comment: @womble I agree entirely.  I have been trying very hard to get folks to leave SELinux enabled and create custom policies.  I am working on that in my company and I foresee a long uphill challenge, but I will not give up.

Comment: @womble: I thought I was the only one who gets frustrated with "sudo su -"

Answer (score 11):

First off, never use root to execute day-to-day commands.

That's the best way to actually expose yourself to disasters.

With that in mind, if you use sudo, you can actually limit commands AND the command options that a user can execute with sudo.

For example, in your sudoers file, you can limit using rm like so:

```
myuser ALL=(root)   NOPASSWD: rm -r
```

This would mean that *myuser* can only use sudo as *root* and can only execute *rm* with the *-r* option.

The sudoers file also support regex so you can really customize what can be executed while using sudo.

[A good starting point](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers)...

Comment: Upvoted for "never use root to execute day-to-day commands."

Comment: I know that folks will disagree with me on this, but folks have been conditioned to believe sudo prevents such mistakes and it simply isn't true.  In fact, it makes super-user level mistakes much easier and more common, in my experience of recovering systems that folks have broken.  There is a psychological aspect to this topic however and I know that this will continue.

Comment: @aaron, I have the exact opposite experience. Since we enforced strict sudo, auditd, sshd and pam settings, the amount of mistakes that are going through has decreased drastically. On top of it it makes it so much easier to know who did what. In turn making it easier to do a rollback in case of problems.

Comment: Note: If you specify any arguments to a command in `sudoers`, but did not add a wildcard, then you'll only be able to use the command as you gave it, without additional arguments. The example given will allow `sudo rm -r`, but not `sudo rm -r foo`, or `sudo rm -ri foo`.