# Accidentally rm -r /* to my ubuntu cloud server

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I've made a huge mistake by running `rm -r /*` on my ubuntu 16.04. But i managed to cancelled the on going command quickly using `ctrl-c`. Now all my bash is not working. For example if i type '`ls`' in my directory, it will show '`command not found`'. it seems that all command is affected and i just can use cd command.

what i found out is that my files at `/var/www/html` is still intact and not deleted and my web application is still running with minor issues.

I have done the change PATH fix but i found out that my `/bin` is deleted and my home directory is deleted.

**Question 1** : is there any way i can repair my ubuntu 16.04 without losing my files at `/var/www/html`?

**Question 2** : is there any way i can salvage my files at `/var/www/html`?

Comment: Restore a recent backup.

Comment: You probably lost `/dev/` and `/etc` before `/home`, so though luck. Try to `scp -pr` the files away - you might still have `/usr/bin/scp` and `/lib`.

Comment: Better to set up another server and attach current server disk as secondary to a new server. and restore the required web application data.

Comment: thanks for the idea, however i think my bash will not work inside the problem server.

Comment: Attach and reboot from a rescue image, and you will be able to copy and safeguard your remaining data. Then you can try to restore from back-up the files you deleted, or decide to deploy a new system and restore your existing data there (by attaching the disk from the server you nuked) - Also: see https://serverfault.com/q/587102/37681