# Accidentally executed: sudo rm -r /*

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot, amazon-ami

This morning while I was doing a bit of work on my production server, when I accidentally executed the following command:

```
sudo rm -r /*
```

Sadly, the server no longer accept my public key or password for any user via SSH.

And files were hosted on `/home` directory instead of `/var/www` is there any way to restore the files?

And after this incident happen I took **AWS Snapshot** of **AWS EC2**. Then Relaunch it by taking new server.

Although I lost the all my files and project. But I discovered that I still have database. As I've also hosted another application under `/var/www` directory it seems to running fine.

### Would it possible to recover the mysql database from Secondary Image on server?

I tried running executing previous mysql_user and mysql_password on my new server it is not authenticating.

Comment: Achievement unlocked. Congrats. Unlock the next by successfully applying the backups, or an alternate, called "Learned the need of backing up the whole thing".

Comment: Is there a question you have? In other words, what kind of advice do you expect? If you want a way to log in, have you considered logging in at the console, or perhaps booting into single-user mode? After that, it should be easy to fix the login problem and restore the backup. For more focused advice, provide context: What operating system, what server, what options there are to access it etc.

Comment: Is there any way to undo the following?

Comment: Undo what precisely? If you want to go back to the moment before you executed the command, no. However, you can restore a backup, which should come close. If you want something else, say it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Monday morning mistake: sudo rm -rf --no-preserve-root /](https://serverfault.com/questions/587102/monday-morning-mistake-sudo-rm-rf-no-preserve-root)

Comment: I've just created Snapshot. Will it be possible to restore the files using resuce-mode

Comment: Hopefully you're on a reasonably modern Linux distribution with a `rm` binary that treats the '/' differently (that by default uses `--preserve-root`)  and there's nothing to worry https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Treating-_002f-specially.html#Treating-_002f-specially

Comment: @Bob nope: command was including `/*` that means the actual parameters were `/bin /boot /dev /etc` ... once expanded.